# React native app which is running inside expo is not loading

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When I'm running react native application through expo applications, It was loaded up to 100% and didn't continue ahead, remains in the 100%. I tried more times in both emulator and mobile phone, But the Issue was in both.Is Anyone face this and solve ?

Comment: I faced same problem, I solved it by updating my expo phone app.

Comment: Then it will be a issue in latest expo app.